# External data in TileList Flex

Tags: apache-flex, label, itemrenderer, arraycollection, tilelist

I'm working for the first time with a TileList and an itemRenderer and I'm having a bit of trouble getting the information from my array collection to display and looking for some advice. Here's what I've got

```
        private function loadData():void{
        var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
        stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConn;
        stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user ORDER BY user_id ASC";
        stmt.execute();
        var result:SQLResult = stmt.getResult();
        acData = new ArrayCollection(result.data);  
    }   


    <mx:TileList id="userlist" labelField="user_id" dataProvider="{acData}" width="600" height="200" paddingTop="25" left="117.15" y="327.25"> <!--itemClick="showMessage(event)"-->
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
            <mx:VBox width="125" height="125" paddingRight="5" paddingLeft="5" horizontalAlign="center">
                 <mx:Label id="username" text="{}"/>
                 <mx:Label id="userjob" text="{}"/>
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:TileList>
```

So I'm just not sure how I go about pulling the information from the array and putting it into labels like username, userjob, userbio ect, Inside the TitleList and itemRenderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<mx:Label id="username" text="{data. username}"/>
```